# TableLayoutPanel and Resizing/Location

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have an application with several controls (richtextboxes and buttons) within TableLayoutPanels within other TableLayoutPanels.

With the click of a button, I need the richtextbox in the topmost TableLayoutPanel to extend to the bottom of my application.

I have thought of two ways of possibly accomplishing this:

- I need all of the other TableLayoutPanels resized to a height of 1px or something very small regardless of their controls and then stretching the TableLayoutPanel at the top of my application to the bottom.

  - I tried TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles(0).Height = 1 but nothing happens.
- Creating a richtextbox outside of these TableLayoutPanels and then moving it on top of the richtextbox for the TableLayoutPanel at the top of my application and then resizing it to reach the bottom of the page.

  - Problem: I tried rtbTextBox1.location = rtbTextBox2.location but it isn't working. My suspicion is that it won't work because rtbTextBox2.location is within a TableLayoutPanel, throwing off the actual position.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if i proper inderstood your question, but i try to give an answer the same.

Let's say we have an outer TableLayoutPanel (tlpOuter), with 2 rows and 2 columns. In its upper left cell, it contains another TableLayoutPanel (tlpInner), with 2 rows and 2 columns. tlpInner contains a RichTextBox (rtbMain) in its upper left cell. tlpOuter has a size of (800,500).

Try this

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    tlpOuter.ColumnStyles(0).SizeType = SizeType.Absolute
    tlpOuter.ColumnStyles(0).Width = 800
    tlpOuter.RowStyles(0).SizeType = SizeType.Absolute
    tlpOuter.RowStyles(0).Height = 500

    tlpInner.Size = New Size(800, 500)

    tlpInner.ColumnStyles(0).SizeType = SizeType.Absolute
    tlpInner.ColumnStyles(0).Width = 800
    tlpInner.RowStyles(0).SizeType = SizeType.Absolute
    tlpInner.RowStyles(0).Height = 500

    rtbMain.Size = New Size(800, 500)

End Sub
```